# Multiple systemd broken links, system won't boot

Tags: boot, package-management, snap, systemd, symbolic-link

On a reboot today, the system (Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.4) hung upon reaching the graphical target.  Conspicuously, several services failed to start ahead of this, including snapd.

Booting the machine to stick and rooting around the configuration files revealed a large number of broken symlinks in the systemd subdirectories.  These broken links include, among others:

- a link named snapd.service targeting /lib/systemd/smartmontools.service.  This is odd because the names don't match and because the target exists;
- every user-created link.  I should hasten to add these are plain-vanilla links from "systemctl enable" for simple .service units running simple scripts.

Removing the broken links allowed the machine to boot but without multi-monitor support and snapd and all snaps disabled.

Any thoughts about what might be at work and how to fix it would be most appreciated.

Comment: anacron will run on the hour after you first boot. It maybe coincidence that it happened while snapd was trying to start. If you suspect gdm3 try uninstalling and reinstalling it. You can restore missing links with `systemctl enable servicename` but it may be more pragmatic to reinstall. One possibility is an imminent disk failure so I’d prioritise recovery of any important data that you don’t have backed up

Comment: And I would check hard-drive too.

Comment: The "hard drive" is a freshly created hardware RAID 6 array that the card's BIOS reports is optimal with no SMART errors, so I don't expect drive failure is at work.  LMK if other hardware issues in this configuration come to mind.

Comment: I can't run anything on this system directly because one of the services that fails is logind, so I get no login prompt when I switch to tty (ctrl+alt+f5).  Just out of curiosity, is it possible to chroot the entire partition while booted to stick?  Reinstall is looking like the best bet but doing this first might surface some errors that I could avoid on the next attempt.